# Android::Does a view know when it is scrolled?

Tags: android, view, scrollview

I have a ScrollView and views inside it.

I want to have special behaviour on one of the child views in the ScrollView. My question is, does the view itself know when it is scrolled? Is there a callback, like onScrollChanged or something that can notify my view that the scroll in the scrollView is changed?

The views should not know about the parent scrollview.

I tried using ViewTreeObsever, and registering a onScrollChangeListener callback, but for some reason I get no callback whatsoever when I scroll things.

Comment: Can you tell us some more about what you're trying to accomplish? What sort of special behavior?

Answer (score 3):

There is the [OnScrollListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.OnScrollListener.html) which handles scroll events.

Comment: See, here is the deal - I am dynamically buidling a view hierarchy  in the code-behind and the added views do not know about the parent scrollView,  I they should not know about the parent scrollView. Also, I am using a custom (extended) ScrollView, which does not extend AbsListView, and I dont think I should extend AbsListView.